# R cleaning data - amatch to merge close matches from 2 separate data frames

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I'm having tough time figuring out the amatch function in R.

2 data frames, respondent (with user input) and census. I have already normalized and merged user input with perfect matches from the census. I would now like to do a "closest match" to narrow down the remaining (as of yet unmatched) respondent entries. Do I nest amatch inside of the merge function? I've read the amatch documentation and done an extensive search, but haven't been able to make it work.

I can't even get a TRUE / FALSE output, trying to follow the documentation:

```
library(stringdist)
closest <- amatch(respondent, census, nomatch = 0, match NA = TRUE)
```

[respondent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgHmZ.png) [census](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZjJp.png) [desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYvxE.png)

```
> dput(respondent)
structure(list(respondent = c(196L, 197L, 204L, 209L, 214L, 215L, 
220L, 225L, 226L, 228L, 229L), resp_input = structure(c(1L, 10L, 
7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 11L), .Label = c("Bramppton", 
"Brookfield", "Caledonn", "Cartwright", "Durham Region", "Halifax / ", 
"Kinuso", "Kleowna", "St. Paul/Saddle Lake", "Tornto", "watsonlake"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("respondent", "resp_input"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
> dput(census)
structure(list(code = c(3520005L, 3521005L, 3521010L, 3521024L, 
5935010L, 5953012L, 5953019L, 5953023L, 5953033L, 6001003L, 6001004L, 
6001006L), census_title = structure(c(11L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 
4L, 9L, 6L, 12L, 3L, 10L), .Label = c("Brampton", "Caledon", 
"Faro", "Fraser-Fort George H", "Kelowna", "Mackenzie", "McBride", 
"Mississauga", "Prince George", "Teslin", "Toronto", "Watson Lake"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("code", "census_title"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Ronak's answer, check out the `fuzzyjoin` package which simplifies the process of joining on a fuzzy string match:

```
fuzzyjoin::stringdist_join(
  x = respondent, 
  y = census, 
  by = c("resp_input" = "census_title"),
  method = "osa",
  ignore_case = TRUE,
  max_dist = 3,
  mode = "inner"
  )

#>   respondent resp_input    code census_title
#> 1        196  Bramppton 3521010     Brampton
#> 2        197     Tornto 3520005      Toronto
#> 3        209    Kleowna 5935010      Kelowna
#> 4        215   Caledonn 3521024      Caledon
#> 5        229 watsonlake 6001003  Watson Lake
```

You can play around with the various [methods](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringdist/versions/0.9.5.5/topics/stringdist-metrics) and `max_dist` parameter to get the best result for your data.

Comment: wonderful :) max_dist = 2 seems to be the magic number for my data set

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with `maxdist` value :

```
stringdist::amatch(respondent$resp_input, census$census_title, maxDist = 5)
```

from `?amatch`

> maxDist - Elements in x will not be matched with elements of table if their distance is larger than maxDist.

Maximum distance between string is dependent on the method that you select to compare two strings. Also note, that `amatch` returns the index of closests match.

Comment: I'm sure this is a fine solution, but I'm too much of a noob to get amatch to work on my data